# Cakephp find hostname from url in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I need to find host from referrer URL in CakePHP.
I can do same in core php with `parse_url` function. I have tried `Router::parse` function but it gives me output in from of array of controller, action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get hostname by

```
  $pieces = parse_url(Router::url('/', true));
  print $pieces['host'];
```

Comment: this gives output as http: // www.example.com, I need only host part like 'www.example.com'

Answer (score 5):

If you're within a controller, `$this->request->host()` will return the host directly.

Answer (score 2):

Whithin a controller or view

```
$host = $this->request->host();
```

Other files:

you can use:

```
$host = Router::getRequest(true)->host();
```

Or:

```
$request = new CakeRequest();
$host = $request->host();
```